# Creating Ad Creatives using Facebook Marketing API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to create an ad creative that links to an external landing page, with URL tags. The [Marketing API Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/validation/v2.12#creative) provides the following example (slightly modified):

```
curl \
-F 'name=Sample Creative' \
-F 'title=my title' \
-F 'body=my body' \
-F 'url_tags=utm_medium=tag=TAG' \
-F 'object_url=https://www.link.com' \
-F 'link_url=https://www.link.com' \
-F 'image_hash=<IMAGE_HASH>' \
-F 'access_token=<ACCESS_TOKEN>' \
 https://graph.facebook.com/v2.12/act_<AD_ACCOUNT_ID>/adcreatives
```

This generates an error with the message:

> Ads and ad creatives must be associated with a Facebook Page. Try connecting your ad or ad creative to a Page and resubmit your ad.

If I include `-F 'object_id=<PAGE_ID>'` I get a different error:

> The object you are trying to promote is ambiguous. You must specify only one promoted object. You specified the following: object_id, object_url.

If I then remove the object_url field, but retain link_url, I get:

> Creative must have a valid destination URL, and if attached object is page, destination must match page.

Using actor_id or page_id instead of object_id does not resolve the problem.

The only way I can get the call to run without an error is something like:

```
curl \
-F 'name=Sample Creative' \
-F 'title=my title' \
-F 'body=my body' \
-F 'object_id=<PAGE_ID>' \
-F 'url_tags=utm_medium=tag=TAG' \
-F 'image_hash=<IMAGE_HASH>' \
-F 'access_token=<ACCESS_TOKEN>' \
 https://graph.facebook.com/v2.12/act_<AD_ACCOUNT_ID>/adcreatives
```

However, that does not contain the link to the external website.

It appears the Nov, 2017 policy change requiring ad creatives to be associated with an existing Facebook page (which I have) means that there is no combination of object_id, object_url and link_url to let me do what I want to do.

Comment: Still happening as of 3.2. Also, this seems related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52273304/creating-adcreative-on-facebook-api-getting-error-subcode-1885833

Comment: So I eventaully got my solution working, I have updated my answer with code, might help other people seeing working code in php.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52273304/creating-adcreative-on-facebook-api-getting-error-subcode-1885833