# Creating adcreative on facebook api getting error_subcode 1885833

Tags: php, laravel, facebook, facebook-graph-api

When trying to create an adcreative on facebook using api 3.1 i was getting this error:

```
[2018-09-10 10:45:47] local.INFO: array (
  'message' => 'Invalid parameter',
  'type' => 'OAuthException',
  'code' => 100,
  'error_subcode' => 1885833,
  'is_transient' => false,
  'error_user_title' => 'Ad Must Be Associated With a Facebook Page',
  'error_user_msg' => 'Ads and ad creatives must be associated with a Facebook Page. Try connecting your ad or ad creative to a Page and resubmit your ad.',
  'fbtrace_id' => 'FUMJg2Q2z1e',
)
```

Comment: Seems related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49481930/creating-ad-creatives-using-facebook-marketing-api. I'm also looking for an answer for this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found this solution on a Facebook page post

> =Breaking Change: Event Ads, Link Ads not Associated with Valid Page=
>
> We recently announced an initiative to make the Facebook Advertising
>   platform more transparent to Facebook users. Read more about this in
>
> To support this initiative, we're deprecating Event Ads and Link Ads
>   that are not connected to a valid page from the Marketing API.
>
> This breaking change impacts all supported API versions, including the
>   upcoming Marketing API version v2.11, and v2.10 and v2.9, which are
>   available, but will be deprecated. This breaking change will take
>   effect the week of Nov. 6, 2017.
>
> As a result of this breaking change, you will no longer be able to
>   create or edit Event Ads and Link Ads that are not connected to a
>   valid page. Requests to do so will return the error:
>   'ErrorCode::ADPRO2__AD_MUST_HAVE_PAGE (1885833)'.

Failing options

> The following ad options used together will fail:
>   ===Event Ads===
>   - Objective: 'EVENT_RESPONSES'
>   - Creative fields: 'body, object_id'
>   === Link Ads ===
>   - Objective: 'LINK_CLICKS'
>   - Creative fields: 'title', 'body', 'object_url' containing 'image_file' or 'image_hash'
>
> You can still create Event Ads and Link Ads if you provide a valid
>   'actor_id' in the ad creative's 'object_story_id' or
>   'object_story_spec' fields.

Valid options

> These options used together are valid:
>   === Event Ads ===
>   - Objective: 'EVENT_RESPONSES'
>   - Creative fields: 'object_story_id' or 'object_story_spec'
>   === Link Ads ===
>   - Objective: 'LINK_CLICKS'
>   - Creative fields: 'object_story_id' or 'object_story_spec'

Link from: https://www.facebook.com/marketingdevelopers/posts/=breaking-change:-event-ads-link/1469189583195436/

EDIT----

Eventually i got it working, it was a combination of problems. the main problem was that the adcreative was set up in a way that was not allowed, facebook docs don't match to what you are allowed to do. So this is my working adcreative in php

```
$data = file_get_contents($imageUrl);

$data = [
    'bytes'        => base64_encode($data),
    'access_token' => $this->accessToken,
];

$response = $this->client->request('POST',
    "act_{$accountId}/adimages", [
        'form_params' => $data,
    ]);

$response = $this->readStream($response)->images->bytes;

$link = (object)[
    'link' => $linkUrl,
];

$signUp = (object)[
    'type'  => "SIGN_UP",
    'value' => $link,
];

$linkData = (object)[
    'call_to_action' => $signUp,
    'link'           => $objectUrl,
    'image_hash'     => $response->hash,
    'message'        => $body,
];

$objectStory = (object)[
    'link_data' => $linkData,
    'page_id'   => $pageId,
];

$data = (object)[
    'name'              => 'system-generated-' . $accountId,
    'title'             => $title,
    'object_story_spec' => $objectStory,
    'access_token'      => $this->accessToken,
];

$response = $this->client->request('POST',
    "act_{$accountId}/adcreatives", [
        'form_params' => $data,
    ]);
```

And this is how I create the actual ad

```
$creative = (object)[
    'creative_id' => $creativeId,
];

$data = (object)[
    'name'         => $name,
    'creative'     => $creative,
    'adset_id'     => $adSetId,
    'status'       => "PAUSED",
    'access_token' => $this->accessToken,
];

$response = $this->client->request('POST',
    "act_{$accountId}/ads", [
        'form_params' => $data,
    ]);
```

Comment: Were you able to make it work in the end? I haven't. I've tried `actor_id`, `object_id` and so forth, and the error just persists.

Comment: @Alex updated my answer with working code, used guzzle to send the requests. The error I got was not why it was not working, if you don't set the adcreative up right it will throw unrelated errors... The docs are also out of date... So maybe my working code helps.

Comment: Thank you so much for this! Been stuck on this for a full day, the documentation is all over the place. It's important to make these `AdCreativeLinkData` things whenever you're advertising a link – and then packing it into an `AdCreativeObjectStorySpec`.

Comment: @Ali glad it helped! I was so annoyed before I figured it out, so I thought I could save someone else the trouble.

Comment: First of all, thanks for all this. Helped me at least get a grasp what the issue actually was. im using java sdk and its basically the exact same thing, except i had to figure out which classed to actually use for each object. the only thing im missing is "pageid". where exactly did you get that from. using another api call or manually inserting it? if its manually inserted, where do i find mine?

Comment: ok i figured it out: create a facebook page using the dev account. under marketing API select Tools, click on "Edit Sandbox Ad Account" and then select the page you just created. it will show your id there

Comment: @Alan great that it helped, my system used the javascript SDK to create a select box with the users owned pages, it would then send the selected page with the accompanying pageId to the server that would then handle the ad creation. That is why you do not see the pageId anywhere in the code